# puppet lambda block failing parser validate

Tags: puppet

I am trying to learn puppet by reading a book. The book has a very simple example showing iteration using a lambda block with `each`. However, I am unable to execute it on my Ubuntu box.

```
/vagrant/manifests/mountpoints.pp

$data = ['routers']
$data.each |String $item| {
    notify {$item:
        message => $item
    }
}
```

The code fails to validate with `puppet parser validate` and I am not able to determine why.

```
[tmp]$puppet parser validate /vagrant/manifests/mountpoints.pp
Error: Could not parse for environment production: Syntax error at '.' at /vagrant/manifests/mountpoints.pp:2
```

My question is: what is wrong with this sample code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your book actually has that, then you should probably stop using that book. That has never been proper syntax for a lambda, even back with 3.8 and the future parser.

Proper syntax is:

```
$data = ['routers']
$data.each |$item| {
  notify {$item:
    message => $item
  }
}
```

or with a cleaner/tidier style (given only one element, resource, and one parameter that is duplicate with the title):

```
['routers'].each |String $item| { notify { $item: } }
```

https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_iteration.html has some helpful documentation on iterative lambdas.

It is also worth noting that you must either be using Puppet >= 4 or Puppet >= 3.2 <= 3.8 with the future parser enabled to use lambdas in your code.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but again get an error..Let me update the question with your code.. I did modified the example given in the book a little bit to debug it more.

Comment: @JayRajput My code is valid and works correctly. I have to assume you are using a version of puppet that does not support lambdas. Make sure you are either using Puppet >= 4 or 3.8 with the future parser enabled.

Comment: I enabled the future parser in the puppet.conf and it worked. Thanks for the help

Comment: @JayRajput Sure, let me update the answer for that too.